# Python - Sending Packets issuing error - Minecraft Packets

Tags: python, struct, send, packet, minecraft

**I'm using the following script:**

```
import socket
import struct

username = "username_value"
verification_key = "verification_key"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # boilerplate
s.connect(("example.com", 1234))  # adjust accordingly

# now for the packet
# note that the String type is specified as having a length of 64, we'll pad that

packet = ""

packet += struct.pack("B", 1)  # packet type
packet += struct.pack("B", 7)  # protocol version
packet += "%-64s" % username  # magic!
packet += "%-64s" % verification_key
packet += struct.pack("B", 0)  # that unused byte, assuming a NULL byte here

# send what we've crafted
s.send(packet)
```

**and getting a response of:**

```
    packet += struct.pack("B", 1)  # packet type
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

**I am almost brand-new to Python, and just started, but I understand the language. I read up and found something about Python 3 changing the way you use packets. I feel kind of hopeless. Help? Thank you**

Answer (score 2):

In python 3 you have to implicitly define your string `packet` as a bytes

```
packet = b""
```

instead of `packet = ""`

Comment: So, instead of packet += struct.pack("B", 1), it'd be packet = b"1"

Comment: @EvanJerald Nope, `b'\x01'`. Feel free using `struct` in Python 3. That's not an issue.